# Whenever Laplace's equation is solved in $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, the boundary $\partial{\Omega}$ is one-dimensional. ...

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem

My introductory PDE textbook has this figure in a chapter on boundary and initial data:

[image]

It then says

> Note that whenever Laplace's equation is solved in $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, the boundary $\partial{\Omega}$ is one-dimensional. When solving the equation in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the boundary is two-dimensional, so that there are two tangential derivatives and one normal derivative at every point on the boundary.

Why is this? This is not clear to me.

Please help me understand this.

Comment: As an example, let $\Omega$ be the $xy$ plane $\{(x,y,0)\in\mathbb R^3\}$ with normal vector $(0,0,-1)$.  Then there are three possible derivatives at $z=0$: the normal derivative $-\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f(x,y,z)|_{z=0}$, and the two tangential derivatives $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y,0),\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y,0)$.

Comment: @user254433 Your example is a good one. I just read it again and it makes complete sense. I'm not sure why I didn't understand it in the first place. Must be sleepy? Of course if $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, then the boundary $\partial{\Omega}$ is one-dimensional! And analogously for $\mathbb{R}^3$... This is so obvious... Sorry everyone!

Answer (score 1):

**Explanations with manifolds :**

PDE are solved on open sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Open sets are manifolds. The boundary of a manifold of dimension $n$ is a manifold of dimension $n-1$.

More intuitively, you can find coordinate charts going from an hyperplane of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to the boundary. Coordinate charts being basically homeomorphisms (continuous bijections with continuous inverse).

Manifolds of dimension $m$ are space that can be seen locally as $\mathbb{R}^m$. This means that locally (around a point) we can find an homeomorphism between our manifold and an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Often, we also assume that the boundary of the open set is $C^1$. Typically, this seems to be the case on your drawing, but would not have been if $\Omega$ was a square (because of the corners), for example.
By assuming this, we always can find $n-1$ tangential derivatives and $1$ normal derivative.

Note : sorry if you are not familiar with manifolds, but they are the most rigourous way to talk about this.

Comment: I just read it again and it makes complete sense. I'm not sure why I didn't understand it in the first place. Must be sleepy? Of course if $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, then the boundary $\partial{\Omega}$ is one-dimensional! And analogously for $\mathbb{R}^3$... This is so obvious... Sorry everyone!

Comment: By the way, I have never studied manifolds, hahaha. I will accept your answer anyway, since others might benefit from it.

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure you should accept answer without knowing if what has been said is reasonnable and helpfull.

Comment: You have high reputation, so I trust that you know what you are doing. Would you like me to remove it? I can wait till people upvote your answer and then do it later?

Comment: It is probably better that way indeed. Thank you.